# I would like some ideas or instructions on how to upload files to git remote if I change computers

Tags: git, github, gitlab

[image: Expected result]

On Dec 2023, I have already push file to gitlab. The local is same as the remote.
On Jan 2024, I changed my computer and modify the files inside the folder. I have already attach the image.

I try to use `git pull origin master`
There is an error message:
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
0
1
2
3
4
Please move or remove them before you merge.
Aborting

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+pull+%22The+following+untracked+working+tree+files+would+be+overwritten+by+merge%22

Comment: If your local is the same as the remote, why not just clean all local files and pull?

Answer (score -1):

You need to pull changes from remote first:

```
git add .
git stash
git pull
git stash pop // Fix any conflicts, if any
git push
```

Comment: "*The following **untracked** working tree files would be overwritten by merge** vs `git stash`? (Emphasize mine, downvote not mine).

Comment: @phd Then use the "include-untracked" flag

Comment: @Kim I know. I pinged Justinas because that should be in the answer.